# MySQL table is locked, but not in a processlist

Tags: mysql, innodb

I tried to execute the following:

```
delete from my_table where id = 19262202
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

So I tried to see the list of locked tables by this:

```
show open tables where in_use>0;
```

but I don't see any locked tables. How do I find out if the table is locked or do I have to deal with different problem?

My table is using `InnoDB` engine.

Comment: Anything in `SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS` or `SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_LOCKS`?

Comment: Both are empty.

Comment: Maybe it's because my table has over 17 mln rows. What is the acceptable limit value for delete statement from large tables?

Comment: I would run `EXPLAIN` on your query to determine why it is taking so long and timing out while locked, but unless there are a lot of foreign key references to the id, it should hit the index and be pretty fast. Ultimately table size performance impact depends on server resources, typically you would want to implement partitioning or clustering to improve performance on large datasets.

Comment: The information_schema tables will be empty unless there is a lock-wait *in progress*. That is, some transaction with a lock, and another transaction (e.g. your DELETE) that is waiting on the lock. If there aren't both, then INNODB_LOCK_WAITS will not show anything.

Comment: Note also that the transaction that holds the lock isn't necessarily running a query. It just holds a lock that it acquired by some earlier query, and hasn't finished the transaction yet. So it might show as "sleeping" in the processlist, yet still hold locks. There isn't any way of discovering the query that grabbed the locks.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: How many rows have `id = 19262202`?  Is `id` indexed?